# How to open a local pdf file from the desk using PDFViewerApplication with "Pdf.js" in java?

Tags: java, pdf.js

I am trying to open a Pdf file from the local storage with pdf.js in java, but it seems like I am passing the pdf path in wrong format, or the Pdf.js only supporting opening a file when it is inside the project.
Wondering if anyone can help...

```
    WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

    File file = new File("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\filename.pdf");

    String pdfViewer = PdfWebViewController.class.getResource("web/viewer.html").toString();

    engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    engine.load(pdfViewer);

    // listener to determine if the page has been loaded
    engine.setOnStatusChanged((WebEvent<String> status) -> {
        String s = status.getData();
        if (s != null && s.equals("done")) {

   //This line should call the open pdf file function in Javascript file 
    engine.executeScript("PDFViewerApplication.open('" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "');");

        }
    });
```

Comment: // it is opening the pdf file normally when the file is inside my project using the following code   
        pdfPath = PdfWebViewController.class.getResource("robotpdfjs/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf").toString();
engine.executeScript("PDFViewerApplication.open('" + pdfPath+ "');");

Comment: try to converting windows path to url, something like 'file:///C:/Users/...'

Comment: thanks for your advise, but I already tried this before, still not working